# Set authorization via codebehind in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using Forms Authentication with my custom user Tables (Not ASPNET Membership)
But, I don't want to set Authorization in my Web.Config as Administrator can change the permission at any time.
Is it possible to set Authorization for the current user while logging in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write to a session variable on login, and check this on each page load that it is valid - Id recommend creating a new class that derives from Page that you can inherit from.

Formsauthentication is great though, i'd certainly recommend it. While creating custom logged in states covers all the boxes, if you don't trust your administrators maybe there's other issues :)